# Given positive definite $X\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$, find $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 2}$, such that $YY'\approx X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, svd

Given positive definite $X\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$, I want to find $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 2}$, such that $YY'\approx X$.

---

My attempt:

Using SVD,  $X=U\Sigma U^*$. Let $U_i$ be $i'$th column of $U$, then $Y=[U_1 \quad U_2]\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &  \\
 & \sigma_2
\end{bmatrix}.$

---

I am not sure if this is a correct approach. Assumption: $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2\geq \sigma_3\geq \sigma_4$. I think if $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_4$ are very small compared to $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ then it might work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct. Instead, however, you should take
$$
Y=[U_1 \quad U_2]\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\sigma_1} &  \\
 & \sqrt{\sigma_2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In particular, we find that
$$
YY' = U \pmatrix{\sigma_1 \\ & \sigma_2 \\ & & 0\\ &&& 0} U'
$$
is a good approximation for $X$. In fact, the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) tells us that this $YY'$ is closer to $X$ than any other matrix of rank $2$.

Comment: thanks, good to know this theorem